# Lazy Load Images in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uitableview

I am lazy loading some images in a table view

I followed the below tutorial 
  [Lazy Load ios](http://www.theappguruz.com/sample-code/ios-lazy-loading-images/)

This is the cell style which I want to display.
[image: Table Cell View]

The problem is on the server side image is too big so the image view takes the full width and height of the image. Which results in an abrupt display of the table.

I cant reduce the size on the server. Isnt there any way with which I can set the image height and width for all images that are being lazy loaded.

```
      - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"videoCell1";

CellTableViewCell *cell =(CellTableViewCell *)[tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"videoCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}

cell.videoNameLabel.text = [videoTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


cell.videoImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

[cell.videoImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[videoImage objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];


return cell;
}

    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
return 200;
}
```

Plus on scrolling the table view it also disrupts. How do I solve the issue? Any suggestions.

Comment: Before saving the image in your _diskCachePath, resize the image and then save.
When you scroll the table view it will load smaller size images and it looks smooth scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at [PHImageManager](http://nshipster.com/phimagemanager/)

Example code in swift

```
var assets: [PHAsset]
var imageRequests: [NSIndexPath: PHImageRequestID]

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let manager = PHImageManager.defaultManager()

    if let request = imageRequests[indexPath] {
        manager.cancelImageRequest(request)
    }

    let asset = assets[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(asset.creationDate, dateStyle: .MediumStyle, timeStyle: .MediumStyle)

    imageRequests[indexPath] = manager.requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0), contentMode: .AspectFill, options: nil) { (result, _) in
        cell.imageView?.image = result
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This almost worked for me, had to change some stuff for Swift 3. `var imageRequests: [IndexPath: PHImageRequestID]` and the like :)

Answer (score 0):

The cell reusing is not properly implemented.

Add this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidload];
    [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"videoCell" bundle:nil]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"videoCell1"];
}
```

And remove this code

```
if (cell == nil) {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"videoCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: getting this error 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'cell reuse indentifier in nib (cell1) does not match the identifier used to register the nib (videoCell1)'

Comment: you have defined cell reuse identifier to cell1 (open it in interface builder and change to "videoCell1"), or change in the code to "cell1"

Answer (score 0):

Before saving the image in your _diskCachePath, resize the image and then save. When you scroll the table view it will load smaller size images and it looks smooth scrolling.

For resizing the image use the following method. This will maintains the aspect ratio when resizing the image.

```
-(UIImage*) imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize{

CGFloat width = image.size.width;
CGFloat height = image.size.height;

if ((width/newSize.width) > (height/newSize.height)) {

    if (width < newSize.width) {
        newSize.width = width;
    }
    newSize.height = height*(newSize.width/width);
}
else if ((width/newSize.width) < (height/newSize.height)) {

    if (height < newSize.height) {
        newSize.height = height;
    }
    newSize.width = width*(newSize.height/height);
}
else if(newSize.width > width && newSize.height > height){

    newSize.height = height;
    newSize.width = width;

}
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return newImage;
```

}